# Materialize CSS, custom option in select doesn't work properly on page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I use materialize css and want to use customized dropdown.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an option that will open the modal window.

```
<select>
  <option>some option</option>
  <option>some option</option>
  <option class="custom-option"><a href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">Open modal</a></option>
</select>
```

And in JS I run.

```
$('select').materialize_select();
```

But this removes the `<a>` tag and I can't open my modal this way.

If I replace the JS with:

```
$('.custom-option').html('<a href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">Open modal</a>');
$('select').materialize_select();
```

It works. I don't understand why to be honest.

My problem is that if I refresh the page while the custom option was selected I will be presented with

```
<a href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">Open modal</a>
```

inside the select box which looks ugly. What I want is to show is just

```
Open modal
```

Any ideas?

Comment: An anchor inside an option, really?!  https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option-content-model

Comment: Lol, give me another suggestion then.

Comment: I think you should use change event of select element and open manually modal depending select value or option selected. Can you provide a jsFiddle? BTW, when you say `It works`, have you tested it on chrome? Because this browser doesn't handle click on `option` element and so i guess it won't work anyway on this browser.

Comment: `$('custom-option')` what selector is that? You're missing the `.`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks man. that makes sense, and no it doesn't work on Chrome, thanks for pointing that out.